# How to fix Texas Instruments DAC81408EVM Internal Oscillator error

Tags: spi, dac, texas-instruments, error

So I'm working with Texas Instrument's DAC81408EVM (https://www.ti.com/tool/DAC81408EVM) as an external DAC for a project I'm working on. I'm posting here because TI's forum won't let me ask questions without a company email unfortunately—I don't understand why this is the case.

I've went through two of these DAC81408EVMs so far. Out of the box, they work perfectly fine with the TI USB2ANY and GUI software. However, I want to use an external device (Analog Discovery 2) to send messages via SPI to the DAC board.

However, when I do so, the STATUS register on the DAC gets an "Internal Oscillator Error" (OSC-ALM 0000000000001000). Once this happens, the DAC stops working with the GUI and won't output anything, even with the GUI. I've tried looking online and on TI's support forum, but I can't find any information about how to fix an internal oscillator error (and what causes it in the first place). I'm posting here in hopes that someone has worked with this device before and potentially give me some advice. I'll give some more specific information about my setup below.

Extra Info:

My Vcc=10V, Vss=-10V, Vdd/Vaa=5V, and VIO=3.3V. I'm connecting my external device to the CLK, MOSI, CS, 3.3V, and ground pins on the J8 connector where the USB2ANY connector is supposed to go. I'm not sure if this is what may have caused the problem. Perhaps the J8 connector port was only meant for the USB2ANY connector and not to anything else. I connected it like this, however, because the other available test pins on the board are hard to connect to with wires.

My clock frequency on my external device was set to 8kHz. On the datasheet, it says that the serial clock frequency has a maximum 50MHz. I initially assumed that implied anything below 50MHz would also work, but I could be wrong.

When I try sending 24 bit messages, the messages never send and are always zeroed out (according to the logic analyzer).

I don't know if an internal oscillator error is fixable or not. If it's not, I want to at least know how to prevent it so that I can get another board and do it the right way.

If you need anymore information, I'll be happy to give any. All help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Nick